# xlwings doesn't recognize imported module openturns

Tags: python, excel, openturns

I set up a spreadsheet tool with Python scripts using xlwings. So far so good and everything works fine, I'm running it from Anaconda using Spyder.
I can run the script from Excel (using the VBA connection) and from Python, both are working fine.

Now I'm trying to improve it for which I'm using functions from the OpenTURNS module. So I added the line: `import openturns as ot`. OpenTURNS is installed correctly as I can use its functions in Spyder.

From Spyder I can run the script and write results to Excel, BUT if I run it from Excel I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "DecisionTool.py", line 12, in main
    import openturns as ot
ImportError: No module named openturns
```

So for some reason, while Spyder can find the openturns module, if I do exactly the same thing and run it from Excel it can't find it.
Considering that I can still run everything from Spyder it should be some error in the connection between Excel and Python. However, as I understood, VBA calls python after which Python takes over, so I don't have any clue where to look.
Hope anyone can help.

Comment: The problem is solved. The issue was that the path defined in `PYTHON_WIN` was defined as `c:\restofthepath`
However, the xlwings VBA module has a conditional of the form:

`If Left$(PYTHON_WIN, 2) Like "[A-Z]:" Then`
in which the path is adapted. However, as the condition is defined in capitals the path should be entered as `C:\restofpath` with a capital for the drive.

Comment: Could catch, will try to fix this in a futures release

Answer (score 1):

When you excute Python code through the xlwings VBA module, the default Python interpreter is started, i.e. the same as if you type `python` at the command prompt. So the first thing to check is what happens if you start python at the command prompt and try to import `openturns`. If it can't find it, then Spyder is either using another Python installation or Spyder is somewhere adding the path to the openturns installation.

If Spyder uses a different installation than your default, you can either change the default or set the path to the interpreter in the VBA module, as explained [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/vba.html#settings).

Comment: I had already changed 'PYTHON_DIR = ""' to 
'PYTHON_DIR = "c:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\"' in the xlwings VBA module. According to the comments in the code that should call Anaconda instead of my default Python.
But apparently it doesn't, if I check with another module I get the same error. So even though I put my Anaconda path in VBA it still calls the default Python installation.

Based on your link my xlwings VBA module might have been older, so I reloaded it and set 'PYTHON_WIN' to my Anaconda path but that doesn't help either.

Comment: I tried some other stuff and if I set `OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION` to `True` it runs smoothly. 
Most likely the problem is in the following snippet of code:
`ExitCode = Wsh.run("cmd.exe /C " & DriveCommand & _
                   RunCommand & _
                   """" & WORKBOOK_FULLNAME & """ ""from_xl"" 2> """ & 
LOG_FILE & """ ", _
                   WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn)`
Most likely due to calling cmd.exe and not giving `PYTHON_WIN` as input it still calls the default interpreter, despite what you set in `Function Settings`.

Comment: Problem solved, added the solution in the first post